# Efficiency differences between quadtree and geohashes

Tags: coordinate-system, spatial-database, spatial-index, geohash

I am a newbie to spatial indexing. Can someone please explain me the differences between a quad-tree and geohash. From what I understand both use similar hierarchial methods of dividing the space into 4 quadrants.

However, I am confused as to which one amongst quad-tree and geohash would be efficient for querying and indexing large datasets

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).  This question is at the border between *vague* and *opinion-based*.  Efficiency can be calculated with specific algorithm implementations and a specific dataset, but barring the presence of both, this is more theoretical than is generally permitted here, and may qualify as *too broad* as well.